# Which regexp from compilation-error-regexp-alist is used by compilation-mode?

Tags: compilation-mode

I spent a while debugging the regex in `compilation-error-regexp-alist` only to find that the regex itself is fine.  My current theory is that `compilation-mode` is just actually using a different regex instead.

The error message is: `ERROR: /home/user/projects/lv/packages/client/src/log.ts[291, 11]: 'now' is declared but its value is never read.`

And the regex is: `^[[:blank:]]*\\(?:\\(?:ERROR\\|\\(WARNING\\)\\):[[:blank:]]+\\)?\\((.*)[[:blank:]]+\\)?\\([^(
\n)]+\\)\\[\\([[:digit:]]+\\), \\([[:digit:]]+\\)\\]: .*$`

**How do I see (and change) which regex `compilation-mode` is actually using in a given buffer?**

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a pain to debug.

In my version of `compile.el` you can set `compilation-debug`:

```
(setq compilation-debug 't)
```

Then if you call `describe-text-properties` the `compilation-debug` property then tells you which regexp is matching - along with a few other bits of information.

The following programmatically gets a regexp. (You can run it with `M-x eval-expression`)

```
(car (aref  (car (get-text-property (point) 'compilation-debug)) 1))
```

To get a *name* for this you have this rather ugly bit of elisp (again run with `M-x eval-expression`)

```
(let ((regexp (car (aref  (car (get-text-property (point) 'compilation-debug)) 1)))) (car (car (seq-filter (lambda (x) (equal (cadr x) regexp)) compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist))))
```

You can then reorder `compilation-error-regexp-alist`

Answer (score 1):

It might be any number of the regexp that make up the `compilation-error-regexp-alist`.

One idea would be to place a `message` in `compilation-parse-errors` after both of the `while` loops:  `(while (re-search-forward pat end t) (message "pat: %s" pat) ...`  Add additional messages as needed.

A second idea would be to create a similar `while`/`dolist` loop and search through the finished output to determine applicable matches, and perhaps get a little fancy and stop at each match with a yes/no proceed so that things happen in slow-motion.

A third idea would be to use each individual regexp and open up `M-x re-builder` and try the different regexp on the finished output until you find a match.

A fourth idea would be to add a text-property with the applicable regexp at each location as `compilation-parse-errors` does its thing -- `pat` is the regexp used per `while` loop.  See these with `C-u C-x =` and/or `(text-properties-at (point))`.  E.g., at both locations, `(while (re-search-forward pat end t) (compilation--put-prop file 'regexp pat) ...` will add the regexp to the text-properties placed on the filename.  In the `*Help*` buffer of `C-u C-x =` (on the filename), click on the regexp [show] option -- or, at point on the filename, evaluate `(text-properties-at (point))` and look at the result in the `*Messages*` buffer.  [If it gets truncated, you may need to set a variable to see the full value.... beyond the scope of this question/answer.]

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for the suggestions.  I will give them a go and come back to accept your answer.

Comment: I personally chose to use the fourth option in my own setup.  As long as there is a `file` (filename), the proposed solution works as indicated.  If the `file` is `nil`, then another one of the highlighted regexp areas would need to be selected.  The overhead is minimal and I decided to leave it with the modification for the foreseeable future just in case I ever want to inspect the regexp for whatever reason.  Remember, there are two (2) locations in `compilation-parse-errors` where the while/loops for `re-search-forward` ... `pat` are used ...

Comment: Can you tell me how to select the correct compilation regexp? pulling my hair out here. It has to be so simple I'm not seeing it.